# Tensorflow Serving error serviing tensorflow version 1.5 model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Getting the following error message while run Tensorflow Serving in docker container

```
2019-12-12 03:25:13.947401: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:85] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: mymodel model_base_path: /models/mymodel 
2019-12-12 03:25:13.947870: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating models.
2019-12-12 03:25:13.947891: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:573]  (Re-)adding model: mymodel
2019-12-12 03:25:14.058166: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: mymodel version: 1}
2019-12-12 03:25:14.058430: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: mymodel version: 1}
2019-12-12 03:25:14.059106: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: mymodel version: 1}
2019-12-12 03:25:14.064459: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: mymodel  version: 1} failed: Not found: Specified file path does not appear to contain a SavedModel bundle (should have a file called `saved_model.pb`)
Specified file path: /models/mymodel/1
```

The model has been built using tensorflow v1.5 and does not have a *.pb file. Is it possible to run this version of tensorflow model? any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can deploy model trained on Tensorflow v1.5 on tfserving.**

TfServing requires the `SavedModel` format.

Probably your training script might have some configuration issue. *(But it is hard to pinpoint since you haven't provided the code, always try to include the code in your question on SO for better understanding for others)*

---

### Answer to your question,

For getting the `SavedModel` format, train your model via [official script](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py).

After training, you would get the following directory structure in your specified model directory.

```
<model_dir>
|
|----- variables
|         |------- variables.data-00000-of-00001
|         |------- variables.index
|
|----- saved_model.pb
```

Then you can directly specify the `<model_dir>` path to the tfserving and it will use this model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use h5 for tf serving, but you can easily convert h5 model to SavedModel with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model/best-model.h5')
export_path = './model/1'

tf.saved_model.save(model, export_path)
```

and later use it.